# AEM HTL/Sightly concatenate string in URL to play video in lightbox or PDF in new window

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I'm new to Sightly and AEM development and I'm trying to concatenate the following string href to play a video in a lightbox or open a PDF in a new window.  As I'm trying to get this to work any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <sly data-sly-test="${details.videoPlayingOptions != 'vlp-video'}">
      <a href="${details.pagePath} || '#' || '${gatherInsight.videoLandingPagePath}?vid=${details.videoID}'" class="cta-lightbox" data-videoid="${details.videoID}" target="${details.contentType == 'PDF' ? '_blank' : '_self'}">${details.title}</a>
 </sly>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation is not done in HTL/Sightly with || as your code attempts, that's only used for [logical OR](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#1141-logical-operators).

You should use the [URI manipulation options](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#125-uri-manipulation) as it makes your code more readable:

```
href="${details.pagePath @ fragment=gatherInsight.videoLandingPagePath, query=details.videoIDQuery, context='uri'}"
```

If adding the query map to your use object is not an option you can attempt to concatenate the string using `data-sly-test`:

```
data-sly-test.videoURL="${details.pagePath}#${gatherInsight.videoLandingPagePath}?vid=${details.videoID}" href="${videoURL @ context='uri'}"
```

Comment: Great! I will try this.  Thank you!

Comment: That works like a charm!!  Thank you!!! And that you for sharing the resources for documentation!

Comment: Hi, it seems in the cases of PDFs the lighbox for the video launches.  Is there a way to bypass the lightbox in the case that it's a PDF the user is opening?

Comment: @Reading_code That seems specific to your component